# Assign value to one-to-many field through django code

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

I am trying to assign value to a database entry that is defined using the `models.ForeignKey`. How should I refer to the variables in the referred model?

In the code below, the assignment `update_user.appointments.requester_name = requesting_user` does not work. Googling has not helped me find the right solution. How should one refer to such variables from django/python?

Below is my models.py

```
class AppointmentRequest(models.Model):
    my_name = models.TextField(default='')
    requester_name = models.TextField(default='')
    meeting_year = models.TextField(default='')


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    firstname = models.TextField(default='')
    lastname = models.TextField(default='')
    appointments = models.ForeignKey(AppointmentRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to modify the value of appointments entry, i.e., my_name, requester_name, etc.

Below is the code in views.py

```
def book_appointment(request):
    requesting_user = request.GET['requesting_user']
    update_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=requested_user)
    update_user.appointments.requester_name = requesting_user
```

Comment: It looks good to me, just take care of saving it after setting the values, update_user.appointments.save()

Comment: The error I get is this `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'requester_name'. On this line: `update_user.appointments.requester_name = requesting_user`

Comment: so, the foreign key is not pointing to any instance and it's value is None, ensure FK have some value in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're probably getting the "NoneType" object has not attribute "requester_name" is that update_user.appointments is probably null

```
appointments = models.ForeignKey(AppointmentRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

That says your ForeignKey can be null, so that's what it's probably returning to you.

What you should really do is:

```
if update_user.appointments:
    update_user.appointments.requester_name  = request.GET['requesting_user']
else:
    apt_request = AppointmentRequest()
    apt_request.requester_name = request.GET['requesting_user']
    apt_request.save()
    update_user.appointments = apt_request()

update_user.save()
```

This creates an AppointmentRequest object that you use to set the appointments ForeignKey IF update_user.appointments is null.

ALSO, in this code:

```
appointments = models.ForeignKey(AppointmentRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm pretty sure default='' does nothing and it defaults to null. So you can omit that part of the code.

Cont in comments...:
Oh. Another thing. I wouldn't use ForeignKeys for this. I would Use ManyToMany unless the user is only allowed ONE appointment ever.

Comment: What do you mean with the first line after the else case `apt_request = AppointmentRequest()`. Which function should it call?

Comment: Oh. I figured it out. It should refer to the model class instance. Things seem to work now. However, I was under the impression that this would allow one-to-many, i.e., 1 user many appointments. Is this not the case?

Comment: Yes and no. And I think I see what you're doing now. Currently, your design allows Many Users to One Appointment. If you want One user to have Many appointments, you should have the foreign key on the AppointmentRequest model.

Answer (score 0):

```
    requesting_user = request.GET['requesting_user']
```

in this part you are getting the user as json not a django model instance, so when you apply

```
    update_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=requested_user)
```

it doesn't get any thing.

you should use django serializer to make a userSerializer then use it to convert the json user to model instance then when you apply

```
    update_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=requested_user)
```

this should work.